# how to remove(empty) text from a text box?

Tags: php, ajax

how to remove text from a text box like-

```
elseif($num_rows >= 1)
{
?>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("newid").value="";
    </script>
<?php
echo "<font color='Red'><b>$logid</b> Ligin name has already been taken, Please chose another Login name.</font>";
}
```

this code I am using through ajax but this is not working.
`newid id text box control id on php login page`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you like to set innerHTML to empty instead of value:

```
document.getElementById("newid").innerHTML="";
```